Unable to filter on variables in the debugger as described in the docs
In the vscode docs about the debugger it says "Variable names and values can be filtered by typing while the focus is on the VARIABLES section." However when I type in the variables section instead of filtering it is jumping to the next matching value, so for example if I type "a" it will highlight the next variable that starts with "a". Does anyone know why this is different from the docs or how to fix this?

Did you open the find widget for  the Variables view (F3) and is its filter option enabled?  The filter option is the first button that looks like an upside-down pyramid of three lines.

That worked thank you!

What was in the official VS code docs didn't work as expected but hitting F3 opened a search bar where you can click the upside down triangle and filter on the debugger Variables.

I'd encourage raising an issue ticket or pull request in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs to fix this documentation issue. if you do, please add a link here to it
